# Google Maps API Solid State Borders

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When creating a map, the state borders keep coming up as dashed lines.  Is there any way to make them solid?  I am working with the province settings in the json but I cannot seem to find a directive for solid line, perhaps in .stroke?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't do it with [Styled Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling) (and I don't see how you can right now), you could use Styled Maps to hide the state boundaries:

```
 {
    featureType: 'administrative.province',
    elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
    stylers: [{visibility: '#off'}]
  },
```

Then add your own (note that you need a source of the boundaries somewhat consistent with the map tiles).

Example of using borders from a FusionTable

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/qz4jb0r7/1/)

[proof of concept fiddle with styled borders](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/qz4jb0r7/2/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  // Styles a map in night mode.
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 40.674,
      lng: -73.945
    },
    zoom: 7,
    styles: [{
      featureType: 'administrative.province',
      elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
      stylers: [{
        visibility: '#off'
      }]
    }, ]
  });
  var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: 'kml_4326',
      from: '19lLpgsKdJRHL2O4fNmJ406ri9JtpIIk8a-AchA'
    },
    map: map
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: This is great!  I have never heard of fusion tables.  What if I wanted the border to be thicker and blue.  That's the last thing I need.   It's perfect otherwise.

Comment: You can style the polylines from FusionTables. ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/qz4jb0r7/2/))  Updated answer to include a fiddle with thick blue state borders.

Comment: For anyone looking to use this solution in the future: Google is turning off the fusion table layers on Dec 3rd, 2019. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-fusiontables-simple